# Error control of directx camera rotation?

Tags: c++, camera, directx

I use the mouse to control camera rotation in my program(using Directx 9.0c). Mouse X controls the camera to rotate around the Up Vector and Mouse Y controls the rotation around the Right Vector. Rotation caculation is as below:
    `void Camera::RotateCameraUp(float angle)
    {
        D3DXMATRIX RoMatrix;
        D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&RoMatrix, &vUp, angle);
        D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&vLook, &vLook, &RoMatrix);
        D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&vRight, &vRight, &RoMatrix);
    }
    void Camera::RotateCameraRight(float angle)
    {
        D3DXMATRIX RoMatrix;
        D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&RoMatrix, &vRight, angle);
        D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&vLook, &vLook, &RoMatrix);
        D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&vUp, &vUp, &RoMatrix);
    }`
It is supposed that rotation around Up or Right vector should not leads to rotation around the "LookAt" vector, but if I circle my mouse for a while and stop it at the starting point, rotation around the "LookAt" vector has happened. I think it's because of the error while caculating, but I don't know how to eliminate it or control it. Any idea?

Comment: You might want to try rotating about `(0, 1, 0)` in the first method.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: In fact, I do want to rotate about vUp but not (0,1,0). I've explained my mistake when replying cdoubleplusgood. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem. You apply many rotations, and over time, the rounding errors sum up. After a while, the three vectors `vUp`, `vLook` and `vRight` are not normalized and orthogonal anymore.
I would use one of two options:

1.
Don't store `vLook` and `vRight`; instead, just store 2 angles. Assuming x is right, y is top, z is back, store a) the angle between your view axis and the xz-Plane, and b) the angle between the projection of your view axis on the xz-Plane and the z-Axis or x-Axis. Update these angles according to mouse move and calculate `vLook` and `vRight` from them.

2.
Set the y-component of `vRight` to 0, as `vRight` should be in the xz-Plane. Then re-orthonormalize the vectors (you know the vectors should be perpendicular to each other and have length 1). So after calculating the new `vLook` and `vRight`, apply these corrections:

```
vRight.y = 0
vRight = Normalize(vRight)
vUp = Normalize(Cross(vLook, vRight))
vLook = Normalize(Cross(vRight, vUp))
```

Comment: Thank you for advice. I find that the mistake I've made is that "rotation around Up or Right vector should not leads to rotation around the Look vector". In fact, after rotating around vUp for angle alpha and then rotating around vRight for angle beta, we can only come back to the origin state by rotating around vRight for angle -beta and then rotating around vUp for angle -alpha, but not by rotating around vUp for angle -alpha and then rotating around vRight for angle -beta. So when I circle my mouse and come back to the starting point, the camera can not come back to original state.

Comment: Yes, Nico already gave the right answer. I missed that point. Nevertheless, denormalization of the vectors can also be a real problem.